# How to sync the same object in Redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using react + redux to implement a website.
for example, there are two top React components, Dashboard and User, Dashboard shows newest questions, User shows user profile and questions related, this is an single page website, I'll design the state like this:

```
<pre><code>

{
    'dashboard': {
        'questions': [...]
    },
    'users': [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'nickname': 'blabla',
            'questions': [...],
        }
    ]
}

</code></pre>
```

it's highly possible that dashboard and user page contain the same question, if a user change the state of a question on User component(.e.g delete it or close it), how to reflect the change on Dashboard component instantly?

Comment: Check normalizr, it's purpose is to solve problems like you have https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice is to normalize your Redux state structure and avoid duplicate data. A better way to structure your store would be

```
{
   questions: {
      1: {
         id: 1,
         question: '...'
      },
      ...
   },
   users: {
      1: {
         id: 1,
         name: '...',
         questions: [1, 2, 3]
      },
      ...
   },
   dashboard: {
      questions: [1, 2, 5, ...]
   }
}
```

Use a selector to build those array of questions for your component.

```
// selector
const getUserQuestions = (state, userId) => {
    const { 
        questions, 
        user: { 
            [userId]: { questions: userQuestions = [] } 
        } 
    } = state;

    return userQuestions.map(id => questions[id]);
}
```

Here's what your `mapStateToProps` would look like in your `User` page

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        questions: getUserQuestions(state, ownProps.userId)
    }
}
```

[Normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) can help you normalize your state structure and [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) can help you optimize your selectors.